# Excel2016 - Excelformula - Return a date which is not referenced as a Saturday & Sunday

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to return the date (deadline) into a cell sheet which is not on a Sat and/or Sun. So for example, if the starting date is Monday 04/09/2017 and we need 6 days to complete the work, I want the deadline to says Monday 11/09/2017.

Answer (score 2):

The response from User91504 will solve your issue, I will just add to use something like this in your case

```
=WORKDAY(J13,6)-1
```

As the formula is taking the current day into account as part of the leadtime, otherwise it will provide 12/09/2017 as result

Comment: Very Good Point !

Answer (score 1):

=WORKDAY(your start date , number of days to add)

If your date was in Cell J13, then:

```
=WORKDAY(J13,6)
```

Or if you manually type the date, use DATE function:

```
=WORKDAY(DATE(2017,9,4),6)
```